# C Checking for NULL & Error Handling

Tags: c, error-handling

I have functions that perform operations on Strings. For example, `String *concat(s1, s2);` Which would turn s1+s2 and return a new String.

I imagine that another user could send me NULL parameters. 
I could check for NULL.

```
if(s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
  return NULL;
```

And just return NULL.

or I could make the whole program exit with:

```
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I think the best way to solve the problem would be to quit the function and not return anything. However, what if my user is expecting the String and I just return, won't he crash and burn? I also feel that printing to the user would be a bad idea.

I would love to find a way to exit the function and for any case allow the program to continue execution.

Comment: Combining two `NULL` strings would yield another `NULL` string, so what's the confusion.  It should *also* be the responsibility of the callee to sanitize input.  You need to ensure that *you* don't crash for invalid input.

Comment: Or alternatively, you need to ensure you _do_ crash for invalid input - document the interface and assert that it's honoured. Fail fast is also a good strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As C doesn't have exceptions you have to signal error conditions in return values. While in this case returning NULL for invalid input sounds like a good option, you can change the design so that you can return both an error code and the concatenated string: make the function accept three parameters, one of them an out parameter.

```
int concat(string s1, string s2, string *out)
```

The function would return an error code if there's an error, otherwise it writes the result into the out parameter.

Comment: A bit overblown maybe? Anyone who has the brains to check the return code of a concat function is presumably able to make sure not to pass null if the function doesn't handle it!

Comment: @Joni C have a pseudo exception mechanism : setjmp() and longjmp().

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: and you are proposing to use `longjmp` in an `strcat` clone?

Comment: @Nicholas, I am using the concat function as an example to demonstrate a technique that can be applied more generally.

Comment: @n.m you could recreate a strcat clone, but it too complicated, in this case, simply return NULL is one of given args is NULL is quite sufficient

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether NULL are allowed (by design) input values. If they are, you may:

- Return NULL (if it is allowed return value - probably is is, as you assume it is allowed input value)
- Signal some error condition, by returning status code, or use some kind of `errno` value

If NULLs are invalid value, then passing NULL is programmers error so checking must be done by callers of your function. You can use the two previous approaches and you could also:

- Take advantage of "undefined behaviour" and anything could happen. Using assertions is probably the best way to do it:

  ```
  #include <assert.h>

  assert (str1 != NULL && str2 != NULL);
  ```

Using assertions has advantage that in release bulds, you can turn checks off, so you do not have any performance penalty.

Now the important part: *Whichever route you take, document it clearly and stick to it.*